# “There’s food to be cooked yesterday”

Tags: past-participles, to-infinitive

Can I use “there’s food to be cooked yesterday” instead of “there’s yesterday-cooked food”?

It means literally there is food which was cooked yesterday.

Comment: No, because 'to be cooked' means that it hasn't been cooked yet. "There's the food I/you/he cooked yesterday." "There's some food which was cooked yesterday."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Why did I get a downvote?

Comment: @user141460  I think you got downvoted because it's not really clear what you *want* to say, or if you found this sentence somewhere.

Comment: Don't blame me - I didn't downvote! But if you mean 'food which was cooked yesterday', that's the simplest way to say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is a good expression.

If you mean 'food which was cooked yesterday', that's a good way to say it.

"to be cooked..." means that it isn't cooked yet, which contradicts the word "yesterday". And the participle "yesterday-cooked" is unidiomatic.