# “The largest bird ever to exist”

Tags: to-infinitive

As I’ve known, a to-infinitive is used as an adjective referring to something that hasn’t happened yet, but I found a to-infinitive is used to refer to something that has already happened-“the largest bird ever to exist.” Can a to-infinitive refer to something that has already happened?

“Argentavis magnificens was among the largest flying birds ever to exist.”

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentavis

I see no difference between this and the example below.

[“There’s food to be cooked yesterday”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294033/there-s-food-to-be-cooked-yesterday)

Comment: *As I’ve known, a to-infinitive is used as an adjective referring to something that hasn’t happened yet* - can you give an example of this?  There are a lot of ways the to-infinitive is used.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure if this is intentional on your part, but "I have something to drink" may be a bad example, because "have something to drink" idiomatically means the same thing as "drink something", although it could also be interpreted as "I possess something for the purpose of drinking it."  In either case, I don't think the to-infinitive there means "something that hasn't happened yet": It means "for the purpose of".

Comment: @stangdon https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294033/there-s-food-to-be-cooked-yesterday

Comment: @stangdon I think this example is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

To-infinitives have multiple meanings.

It's true that one of those meanings is to refer to an action that will take place in the future (maybe the very near future).  "to cook" in your example does refer to "cook something (in the future)".   And if "to" means "for the purpose of", that also might have a futuristic viewpoint.

However, another usage of "to" can be a generalized, timeless meaning of the verb.

> To live is to suffer. -> living is suffering.

> To err is human; to forgive, divine.  -> erring is human, forgiving is divine.

"to think" can mean "the act of thinking" and not "thinking, in the near future."

So it is with "to exist" here. It means "Existing (at any time)." Not connected to a verb tense. Then by adding "ever", you specifically include the meaning "at any time in the past".

Answer (score 1):

English infinitives are not inflected for tense, and can refer to present, past or future:

- She wants to go.
- She wanted to go.
- She'll want to go.
- It was the largest ever to exist.
- It is the largest ever to exist.
- It will be the largest ever to exist.

There is, though, a periphrastic *perfect infinitive*, e.g. "to have gone", "to have existed".

(There is still no present/past distinction, because the perfect infinitive consists of an infinitive followed by a past participle.  The perfect infinitive is sometimes mistaken for a present perfect, but this isn't the case, as the verb "have" here is untensed.  Sometimes a phrase with a perfect infinitive corresponds to an equivalent phrase with a *past perfect*, e.g. "I was happy to have seen it" = "I was happy that I had seen it".)

But note that "she wanted to have gone" doesn't mean the same thing as "she wanted to go".  (You could perhaps say something like "She doesn't want to study at Oxford, but she wants to have studied there, because it'll look good on her CV".)

On the other hand, "it was the largest bird ever to exist" and "it was the largest bird ever to have existed" mean pretty much the same thing.  But where you want to make clear that its record has since been exceeded, the perfect is preferable: "until recently, it had been the largest bird ever to have existed".